# How to drop index from mongodb schema using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to remove an index from my mongoDB collection in node.js application using mongoose. I tried using `model.collection.dropIndex("username")` but it gives me an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: index not found with name [username]`.

Here is my Schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userTable = new Schema({
  firstname: { type: String, required: true },
  lastname: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String },
  salt: { type: String },
  passwordHash: { type: String },
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  sessionToken: { type: String },
  dateCreated: { type: String, default: new Date().toString() },
  loginHistory: [String]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("userTable", userTable);
```

When I perform the query in mongo shell from the terminal using command `db.usertable.find({})`, I can see that the results still have `username` field. I also tried after removing the `username` field from schema file, but even that didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This drops all the indexes of the collection except for the object id

```
db.collection.dropIndexs();
```

to delete a certain index

first type the command

```
 db.collecction.getIndexes();
```

[image]

You will see something like above the  in the red square is the index name .

```
db.collection.dropIndex( { "indexname": 1 } )
```

Comment: I don't want to drop all the indexes from my database. I just want to drop the username.

Comment: Thank you so much for updating your answer. I ran the suggested command and got the result `> db.usertables.dropIndex({"username": 1});
{ "nIndexesWas" : 3, "ok" : 1 }`
But I can still see that my database entries have the username field. Any idea why is that the case?

Comment: The thing is only the indexes get removed if you want to remove the fields remove them from the mongoose model

Comment: I ran `db.usertables.update({}, { $unset: { username: 1 } }, { multi: true });` and now the username field is removed from the database model. Thank you.

Comment: it's nice to help

Comment: It would be great to name the index and drop it using it's unique name.

Comment: Why is it `username_1` as index name? Does it mean it is the first index for `username`?

Comment: @Timo it's the default way of generating names. Its dosen't mean the first index. . It uses the direction of the index to create a default name. you can specify your own name when creating the index. Have a look here https://www.bmc.com/blogs/mongodb-indexes/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20MongoDB%20will%20generate,name%20when%20creating%20an%20index.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an index using a unique name:

```
      db.collection('users')
      .createIndex(
        { email: 1 },
        { unique: true,
          name: 'users.email.unique_index' }, // here we set index name 
      );
```

and then drop the index using it's name:

```
 db.collection('users').dropIndex('users.email.unique_index');
```